# Why is [hidden] not working after forkJoin().subscribe()?

Tags: angular

I have the following template:

```xml
<div [hidden]="this.days.length > 0" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <div style="font-size: 1.4em; color: #4e4e4e;">
    Empty
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the condition `this.days.length > 0` is not working. After `forkJoin().subscribe({..})`, the list `this.days` is not empty but the `div` above is still not getting hidden.

```js
ngOnInit() {

  forkJoin(
    this.groupService.getData(this.groupId),
    // ..
  ).subscribe(
    data => {

      // .. adding things to this.days ..

      console.log(this.days.length > 0); // Prints 'true'
    });
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: are you mixing up `sortedDays` and `days`? Otherwise, we are going to need more code, like the entire component.ts, are you using OnPush?

Comment: @PierreDuc Sorry that was just a copy & paste error - thanks for the hint. It's `this.days`. The problem is still the same. I never heard of `OnPush` until now. ^^

Comment: You also shouldn't use `this` inside the component, try `[hidden]="days.length > 0"`, or `*ngIf="!days.length"`

Comment: @PierreDuc Thanks! `*ngIf="!days.length"` is doing it - but it's not working with `[hidden]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hidden` attribute sets the style:

```
display: none;
```

But the `fxLayoutAlign` directive [overrides it](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/src/lib/flex/layout-align/layout-align.ts) with:

```
display: flex;
```

---

In order to hide the element, you can define a class style in which the `display` attribute is given a higher priority with the `!important` flag:

```
.not-visible {
  display: none !important;
}
```

and apply that class conditionally to the element:

```
<div [class.not-visible]="this.days.length > 0" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-hctzfs) for a demo.

---

An alternative is to use `*ngIf="!days.length"`, as suggested by [PierreDuc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3106920/pierreduc) in a comment. The result is somewhat different however: instead of just being hidden, the element is not present in the DOM at all when the `ngIf` condition is `false`.